# Event not reflected on Google analytics

Tags: magento-2.1

I am using google analytics for event tracking in magento 2.

I have set up all event data layer in respective page like product page, listing page, checkout page.
All are reflected in Google tag manger preview with data layer. I didn't understand why this is not reflecting in google analytics/ event Overview.
I think this due secured or unsecured url.

Please guide me how control url as by default URL is unsecured with **https://test.decure.in/**

if i remove **s** from https: database i get 500 internal server error on click on every link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Google Tag Manager module I would recommend for Magento 2 -:

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-google-tag-manager

And Put GTM Account Id an Make it enable. Overview the website Home to checkout page 2 - 3 times so data get captured. And It will take time to reflect so check after 3-4 hours or next day.